# sending form with time interval

Tags: forms

Is there any way to send multiple forms for a user in different time intervals?
suppose first, the user fills out form #1.
after submission and checking the form by admin, the second form link will be emailed to the user and this process could be continued. and also it's better to have all forms specified for a user in one place.

Is there any straightforward solution to this problem?

Thank you,

Comment: I edited out the request for a plugin as it would have gotten your question closed as off-topic. This stack is aimed at developers, if you want a product or plugin you should go to the software recommendations stack, otherwise the assumption is that you want to build it yourself

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Is there any software recommendations stack?

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/